# How to install and configure PHPmailer?

Tags: php, configuration, phpmailer

I'm trying to send email with PHP from localhost in wamp. I'm trying to install and configure PHPmailer but I don't no how. I've installed Composer and then from command prompt from folder where is my site I had run this: "composer require phpmailer/phpmailer". Now, in the site folder I have: folder "vendor", files "composer.lock", "composer.json" and folders and files for my site. In "vendor" folder I have folders "composer", "phpmailer" and file "autoload". Then I had tryed this code:

```
`<?php
 require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
 $mail = new PHPMailer;`
```

to check is PHPmailer installed correctly. This code has to be in file which is in folder where "class.phpmailer.php is saved. But there is no "class.phpmailer.php" file.  I saved file with this code in folder where "vendor" folder is. But then I get this:

"Warning: require(PHPMailerAutoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\MySite\checkPHPMAILER.php on line 2

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'PHPMailerAutoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\MySite\checkPHPMAILER.php on line 2".

I could not find file "PHPMailerAutoload.php" anywhere.
Can anyone help me whith this and further configuration. I am new in this so please give extensive explanation as you can.

Comment: You have to have the PHP Mailer Library.

Comment: I installed PHPMailer with Composer. I think I have everything I need.

Comment: I have solve it.

Comment: How you had solved it. Please explain also.

Comment: If I remember correctly first I have installed PHPMailer with composer. Then in php.ini file I have added on line 724: include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;c:\wamp64\www\MySite\vendor\PHPMailer\". And then in phpmailer.php file I have filled required lines with my gmail data (email, password etc.) and it worked. I could sent an email through PHPMailer via my gmail account.